# Getting android.content.res.Resources NotFoundException while saving in shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I want to save text from `EditText` to `sharedPrefs` file named `prefs` in `mode_private` and later on show it in a `textview`.

**code**  :

```
String sal=ed.getText().toString();
        int saly=Integer.parseInt(sal);
        String prefs="myPrefs";
        String Salaryflag="mySalary";
        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences(prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor ed=sp.edit();
        ed.putInt(Salaryflag, saly);
        ed.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Salary Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int c=sp.getInt(Salaryflag, 0);
        String str=Integer.toString(c);

        tv.setText(c);
```

I have put this code in button `onClick`  !

Now  the data which I want to save is of **integer** type .Now the problem is that there is no error shown in code but when I  run code and enter data and click on a button app is crashing causing this error!

```
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Process: com.example.mybalancesheet, PID: 1352
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     ... 11 more
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3a98
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.example.mybalancesheet.MainActivity.salaryEntered(MainActivity.java:60)
09-28 03:11:38.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     ... 14 more
```

Now what should I do to remove it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
tv.setText(c);
```

to

```
tv.setText(str);
```

to use `setText(CharSequence)` which expects a string instead of `setText(int)` which expects a resource id.

Comment: Sry! my foolish fault , May be I was thinking something else X-)